# Angular scrollIntoView after adding an element to NgRx store

Tags: angular, ngrx, js-scrollintoview

I have a list of items that are added dynamically to my view and stored in NgRx:

```
<app-item *ngFor="let item of items$ | async"></app-item>
```

If I click on an "Add item" button the item is added to the NgRx store.

I now want to call `scrollIntoView` on the item reference when a new item is added. I tried to call `scrollIntoView` at `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit` of the item but it gets triggered also on page load. I only want to center the item in the page when it is added to the list AND it is rendered.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why can't you call 'scrollIntoView' method after item got added in to items$ observable in component. You can include those block of code inside setTimeout(()=>{}).

Comment: Isn't setTimeout() an ugly patch? I wouldn't like to go outside Angular to do this.
As for the observable I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you provide example code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can think of:

Create a variable indicating the newly added item index inside items

```
newestIndex; //the index of the newly added item inside items.
```

In your addItem() function, update the index.

```
addItem(item){
  // update item , update ngrx store and also update the newestIndex.   

}
```

Use a ViewChildren decorator to get all component items

```
@ViewChildren(AppItemComponent) appitems: QueryList<AppItemComponent>
```

And now when items update, you can scroll into view.

```
items$.pipe(skip(1))     //skip first value as it is not caused by add item.
.subscribe( items =>{
    this.appitems[newestIndex].nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
})
```

Comment: That's a very good approach! I wonder if there is a solution in which you don't need to rely on a parent component who's got `ViewChildren` references. I'm gonna mark your answer in the meanwhile.